# Configurable products in Magento don't show attributes before I re-save it

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I imported a lot of configurable and simple products. Now I found a problem that configurable products doesn't show dropdown menu for attributes. All configurable products are connected to the attributes properly. Somehow I found out that the solution is to go to the configurable product and just press "Save". Then everything works fine. How should I fix this? I know that I can go to all products manually and save it, but I have so many products, so I am trying to avoid this solution. Thanks for advices.

Comment: try refreshing your indexes instead of re-saving product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem is. So, maybe someone will use this. It was wrong import of the products, so some things were missing. I exported all products and compare working configurable products with non-working and found differences there. After that I will improve my import script to work normally.